# "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation does not exist" In production

Tags: python, django, docker

I've been working on a feature for the past couple of months that hinges on a new one-to-many relation called "user_company". While in the development environment, I only had to migrate once the company model was created and haven't had any problems with it since but I haven't been able to update the production environment due to a "Django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "app_company" does not exist" error.

This throws the docker into a loop of "You can't run the app since it won't compile" and "I can't migrate the tables since the app ain't running" what can I do to either circumvent the error and migrate the table before it fails or ignore the table long enough for it to compile?

Currently the user.company attribute looks like this:

```
...

company = models.ForeignKey(
       Company,
       verbose_name=_("Company"),
       help_text=_("Company name where the user works at"),
       default=Company.get_default(),
       on_delete=models.CASCADE
   )

...
```

while the company model looks like this:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=partial(
      storage.upload_location, path="pidenomina"),
      validators=[file.FileValidator(allowed_extensions=['csv'],
                                     max_size=5242880)],
      verbose_name='File')

    # TODO - Created at

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_default():
        try:
            return Company.objects.first().pk
        except Company.DoesNotExist:
            company = Company.objects.create(id=1, name="Void", description="")
            company.save()
            return company
```

Any help is appreciated, cheers.

Comment: The error message means that your database doesn't have a table named `app_company`. Have you run `manage.py migrate` on your prod environment?